# Error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined, cannot get props

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, filter

i am getting error while trying to filter out items in array. I suppose it is something connected with not right way to approach state or maybe i am not getting props. Main purpose is to filter trainings based on search value and show them in list.

Source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Trainings from '../components/Training';
import CustomForm from '../components/Form';

class TrainingList extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: ''
        };
    }

    updateSearch(event) {
        this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0, 20)})
    }

    state = {
        trainings: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    trainings: res.data
                });
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
        let filteredTrainings = this.state.trainings.filter(
            (trainings) => {
                return trainings.title.indexOf(this.state.
                    search) !== -1;
            }
        );
        return (
        <div>
            <Trainings data={filteredTrainings} />
            <input type="text"
                value={this.state.search}
                onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TrainingList;
```

Comment: Add `training: []` to `this.state`

Comment: @BasvanderLinden where exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

```
state = {
   trainings: []
}
```

to initialize `trainings` (You can remove this code). But the data your filtering is `this.state.trainings`.

So add the initialization of `trainings` to `this.state`:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    search: "",
    trainings: []
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Now i should somehow figure out how to pass unique parameter to map so that i dont get duplicates in my view while searching. It is something connected with "Encountered two children with the same key" error. I dont know exactly how to solve it, but i try.